# python AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'comb'

Tags: math, python-3.7, comb

I'm getting an error when I try to use the 'comb' function:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> print(math.comb(6,49))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'comb'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

The comb function is new in Python 3.8 (see documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)). Your Python installation is 3.7.1. If you update your Python installation, the issue should be resolved.